# Meteor Iron Router passing arraylist value as parameter

Tags: meteor, router, query-string

I am new to meteor and have been trying to pass a value from an arraylist to a href pathfor element.

I have a template

```
<template name="Listing">
  {{#each data}}
    <a href="{{pathFor 'listingbycompanyL1' this}}">{{this}}</a><br/>
  {{/each}}
  <a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
</template>
```

The data being sent into the template using a helper is basically an array of Strings from the following helper

```
'data': function(){
  var distinctOrgListing = _.uniq(MyCustomCollection.find({}, {sort: {orgName: 1}, fields: {orgName: true}}).fetch().map(function(x) {return x.orgName;}), true);
  console.log("Listing.helpers : distinct listings :"  +distinctOrgListing)
  return distinctOrgListing;
}
```

which will return me some data in form of a list of strings. For Example when printed to console i will get

```
Listing.helpers : distinct listings : a,b,c
```

I want to

1. Send the value that i received to Iron Router as a param so that i can use the value do a collection search

My Router configuration for this is as follows :

```
this.route("listingbycompanyL1",{
  path:"/listingL1",
  layoutTemplate: 'ListingbycompanyL1',
  data: function(){
    var update=MyCustomCollection.find({orgName:"XXXX" }).fetch();
    return {
      update:update
    };
  }
});
```

How can i pass the values that i recieved (a,b,c) to IR and use it to do a search, where XXXX is a or b or c

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do in the router. The comment in your router code indicates that you're trying to avoid using a query parameter. At the same time your router is trying to find `orgname: "XXXX"` which has nothing to do with `a,b,c`. Is `a,b,c` always a triple or can be a tuple or a quadruple or any number? Have you thought about just setting a session variable (or reactive variable) in your template helper and referring to it from your route.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Basically I am creating hrefs using #each in the template successfully. I now want to pass value of the href to IR so that i can use this value to query my collection. PS: The comment in the IR is misleading, removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple parameterized route:

```
this.route("listingbycompanyL1",{
  // specify the strategy _id as an URL component instead of query parameter
  path:"/listingL1/:a",
  layoutTemplate: 'ListingbycompanyL1',
  data: function(){
    var update=MyCustomCollection.find({orgName: this.params.a }).fetch();
    return {
      update:update
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would the href be created ? <a href="{{pathFor 'listingbycompanyL1' this}}">{{this}}</a><br/>

Comment: Example: `{{pathFor 'article' _id=this._id }}` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424800/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-pathfor-in-handlebars-for-iron-router-with-meteorite

Comment: Thanks, I update the following `<a href="{{pathFor 'listingbycompanyL1' _id=this._id }}">`  and the IR to `path:'/listingL1/:_id'` but this did not seem to work, my links were not clickable, meaning the path was not getting created properly. I also tried the following `<a href="{{pathFor 'listingbycompanyL1' query='company=mycompanynamehere'}}">` notice that mycompanynamehere is the value i want to send dynamically, in IR i can see this parameter coming through in IR `console.log(this.params.query.company);` The missing part..how can i send the value of {{this}} into mycompanynamehere,.

Comment: Also note that data being sent originally does not have an id, it is a list of strings, that i am iterating in my template and i want to send that string value further to IR, so that i can do a search on my collections. Thanks alot for the help i am still a novice

Comment: My apologies, ir apparently changed since that earlier stack overflow question. [Here's the current documentation on pathFor](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#pathfor)